# Why does my router try to connect with my computer every 1-2 minutes?

Tags: networking, router, firewall

I have every ingoing connections blocked by default. When I was watching syslog, I noticed that my router (192.168.1.1) tries to connect to my computer every 1-2 minutes (of course it can't connect, because I'm blocking it). Have you any idea why is that? Maybe I should allow it? My router is TP-Link TD-W8960N if it matters.

Comment: 'Connect to it' in what way? What port? What protocol?

Comment: What exactly are you seeing in your syslog?

Comment: yes, 'mabey you should allow it', but that 'maybe' depends on what 'it' is.

Comment: Jan 23 16:31:02 enterprise kernel: [11330.419513] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<myMAC> SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2

Comment: I will check port, just need to install wireshark.

Answer (score 3):

Your router is not trying to "connect" to your computer. The destination ip address (224.0.0.1) is the "All Hosts" multicast address and as such all hosts on the same LAN will receive a copy of these packets.

If you want to stop it you need to figure out what multicast services/processes the router has running and disable them.